# How to use Spyne+Django with parameters on url?

Tags: django, xml, soap, url-parameters, spyne

on django urls.py

```
url(r'soap/<str:user_id>/',
    DjangoView.as_view(application=provider)),
```

on views.py

```
@ rpc(_returns=AnyDict)
def super_test_dict(self, one, two):
    user_id = 1 #here need to receive the user_id
    res = {"user_id":user_id}
    return res
```

on tests.py

```
self.soap_client = DjangoTestClient(
        f'/soap/{org.str:user_id}/', provider)
res = self.soap_client.service.super_test_dict()
```

The problem is when i send parameter str:user_id dont work, but if not sent anything work fine, im need to send same parameters as request but also need to send str:user_id on url.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator of your **super_test_dict** method isn't reflecting the input parameters that you're expecting.

I'm not really sure what you intend on doing exactly but to receive inputs into your web service method, change your **views.py** to reflect the following:

```
from spyne import Unicode, Integer

@ rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=AnyDict)
def super_test_dict(self, username, user_id):
    print(f"Hello: {username}, your ID is: {user_id}")
    res = {"user_id":user_id}
    return res
```

Also remember to specify the ***in_protocol*** & ***out_protocol*** in your web service application '***provider***' class

You can also get further details from these [here](https://gearheart.io/blog/how-to-write-an-api-in-django/) and [here](https://ducminhgd.wordpress.com/2017/09/17/create-soap-web-service-with-django/)